# CakePHP creating new record always has id of 1 and overwrites existing

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built a CakePHP app for creating appointments against clients and everytime I try to create an appointment for a client it always overwrites any existing appointment with the same ID of 1. The ID is set to AI in the database so it should auto increment but it's not.

Here is my controller action:

```
function admin_add($client_id)
{
    $this->set('client_id', $client_id);

    $this->set('client', $this->Appointment->Client->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Client.id' => $client_id))));

    $this->set('doctors', $this->Appointment->Doctor->find(
      'list',
      array(
        'fields' => array('Doctor.name'),
        'order' => array('Doctor.firstname', 'Doctor.lastname')
      )
    ));

    if (!empty($this->data))
    {
        if ($this->Appointment->save($this->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'appointments', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
class Appointment extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Appointment';

    var $useTable = 'appointments';

    var $belongsTo = array('Client','Doctor');
}
```

and finally my view for the form:

```
<h1>Book Appointment <em>for</em> <?php echo $client['Client']['firstname'] . " " . $client['Client']['lastname']; ?></h1>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Appointment', array('url' => array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'appointments','action'=>'add',$client_id))); ?>

<fieldset id="post-form">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('client_id',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$client_id)); ?>

            <?php echo $this->Form->input('doctor_id',array('label'=>'<strong>Choose Doctor</strong>'),$doctors); ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('datetime',array('label'=>'<strong>Date and Time</strong>')); ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('treatment',array('label'=>'<strong>Treatment</strong>')); ?>
        </li>
        <li class="sep clearfix">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Book Appointment" />
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Cancel',array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'clients','action'=>'view',$client_id)); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the view fixes the problem:

`<?php echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>`

but why do I need to do this? As clearly the database was able to fill the field with an integer it just didn't auto increment :/

Comment: type hidden is not necessary :)

Comment: why do I need to have the field at all though? as the ID is being created by the DB so why the need for the empty field?

Answer (score 1):

because you have client_id in your Form->create(), so the form changes from add to edit. It's one of Cake's (annoying) automagic. You can just unset that id field before save($this->data)